# How to get callbackurl from twilio API against a twilio number

Tags: c#, twilio

My question is basically about existence of API.
Is there any api from which I can get CallBackUrl against a number?
I have bought a Twilio number (and planning to buy more). Against that number i have configured a CallBackUrl.
Now I need to get the Callbackurl from API. Like I will provide create twilio client

```
var twilioClient = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);
```

then need a API in which I will pass twilio number and it will return back the url
like

```
twilioUrl =  twilioClient.GetCallBackUrl(mytwilioNumber);
```

is there Any possibility of such thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can use the GetIncomingPhoneNumber method to get the details of a specific phone number, including the voice and message request URL's:

```
var result = client.GetIncomingPhoneNumber("PHxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
if (result.RestException == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.VoiceUrl);
    Console.WriteLine(result.SmsUrl);
    Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCallback);
}
```

Hope that helps.